# After setting preserveDrawingBuffer:true, canvas is only rendered after renderer resize

Tags: canvas, three.js

I recently added preserveDrawingBuffer:true to my WebGLRenderer creation to be able to generate screenshots via toDataUrl().
However, now my canvas stays white until I resize the window (and hence the renderer) manually, afterwards the rendering works fine.

I'm creating the WebGLRenderer with the following options:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
  antialias: true
});
```

If antialias or preserveDrawingBufffer is left out, the scene is rendered immediately.

A stripped down example using three.js v68 is accessible via https://jsfiddle.net/ytdoo72k/8/
Firefox v36 shows the behaviour described above, chrome v41 seems to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/ytdoo72k/9/ uses r71 and shows some strange white rectangles.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. While creating the jsfiddle, I spotted the error, see the answer below.

Comment: Thought, I'd found the error, but had no success. Instead I added the jsfiddle and some version info to the question.